# mysql ORDER BY nearest numbers like abs()

Tags: mysql

i need to sort list by $NumValue=85 using mysql. also can use abs()

```
1.25
2.jaban 60
3.india america 70
4.85 africa
5.105
6.syriya sudan uk and 135 us egypt
```

The result of it should be listed like below. please help me.

```
1.85 africa
2.india america 70
3.105
4.jaban 60
5.syriya sudan uk and 135 us egypt
6.25
```

Comment: Don't use mysql for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable 
ORDER BY ABS(MyFieldThatContainsNumber - 85) ASC
```

You can use the above query as long as the number you are needing to sort by is in its own field and not contained in a string.

If this is not the case and the data you are showing above is just a string all in one field, then you will have to parse out the number you want to compare before executing the above query.

***EDIT***

You are working with a bad design.  But if you insist on leaving it that way the this [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5297b/1/0) demonstrates the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (MyField varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Mytable (MyField) VALUES
('25'),
('jaban 60'),
('india america 70'),
('85 africa'),
('105'),
('syriya sudan uk and 135 us egypt');



CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractNumberFromString`(in_string varchar(50)) 
 RETURNS INT
 LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

DECLARE ctrNumber varchar(50);
DECLARE finNumber varchar(50) default ' ';
DECLARE sChar varchar(2);
DECLARE inti INTEGER default 1;

IF length(in_string) > 0 THEN

WHILE(inti <= length(in_string)) DO
  SET sChar = SUBSTRING(in_string, inti, 1);
  SET ctrNumber = FIND_IN_SET(sChar, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

  IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
    SET finNumber = CONCAT(finNumber, sChar);
  ELSE
    SET finNumber = CONCAT(finNumber, '');
  END IF;

  SET inti = inti + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN CAST(finNumber AS SIGNED INTEGER) ;
ELSE
  RETURN 0;
END IF;
END//

SELECT * 
FROM Mytable 
ORDER BY ABS(uExtractNumberFromString(MyField) - 85) ASC
```

Comment: my field contain string and numbers.but i want sort numbers

Comment: That is a bad design then.  All relevant individual pieces of information should be contained in their own field.  If you can change the table structure I would recommend doing so.  It will save you a lot of pain down the road.

Comment: for my convenient i am using string and numbers together.please any more help

Comment: ***@user3284030***, I modified my answer to show you how to extract number from a string.

Comment: What the function does is it gathers all the numbers found within a string and returns them as an integer. The easy way would be to normalize your data and then your number you want to sort on would be in its own field. Since you want to work with a number that appears randomly in a string you have to create your own function. There is no MySQL functions that will do this for you. There is no easier way for the situation.  Also, if you are using this function in a query that returns a lot of records it will probably run poorly.